nested foreach in tcsh
I need to act over several  database clients, these client have a static name APPUSR with numbers (1,11,12,13  2,21,22,23 3,31,32,33 ...) Id.  APPUSR1,APPUSR12, APPUSR3, APPUSR32,....
I thought loop through the tens and other loop for units to create the connection name -
#!/usr/bin/tcsh

set echo

foreach envMast  ( `seq 4 ` )
  foreach envClient ( `seq 0 3 ` )     
if ( "$envClient" == 0) then         
  set envClient = ""   #there is not user 10,20,30 so i blank unit 0 to get envMast 1 2 3 4
endif

sqlplus APPUSR${envMast}${envClient}/APPUSR${envMast}${envClient}@DB <<-EOT>APPUSR.log
SELECT USER FROM DUAL;
exit
EOT
  end
end

It runs ok but only once for APPUSR1.
maybe a simple logic error (I'm newbie on tcsh) but have no idea why it didn't iterate or loop into any of the foreach.

If you are new to shell scripting, probably abandon tcsh for a modern shell without the hideous Csh baggage.

Ist this a typo, or are you really missing a space after -EOT?

Ignoring the sqlplus command, your nested foreach is built correctly.
The problem you're seeing is because your "here document" between <<EOT and EOUT is not working inside the foreach loop.  This doesn't work in tcsh.  (see Bugs section https://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh)
You'll need to find a way to construct your sqlplus command differently.  Maybe you could move those lines into a different file and then source the file from your csh script, like this:
foreach envMast  ( `seq 4 ` )
    foreach envClient ( `seq 0 3 ` )     
        if ( "$envClient" == 0) then         
            set envClient = ""   
        endif

        source sqlcmd.csh >> APPUSR.log

    end
end

